# Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'input' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, rstudio, reactive-programming

I'm trying to allow the user to select which column of data (selecty) they would like to make a plot of. Everything else in my app works except for this part. Here are the relevant portions of my code:

```
#ui.R

library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
shinyUI(fluidPage(h1("Title 1"),
              # Sidebar
              sidebarLayout(
                sidebarPanel(
                  h3("Title 2"),
                  selectInput("pnum",
                              label = "Select the patient number",
                              choices = unique(pnums), selected = pnums[1]),
                  selectInput("selecty",
                              label = "Choose a variable to display on the     y-axis",
                              choices = list('Var1', 'Var2', 'Var3', 'Var4')),
                  dateRangeInput("dates", label= "Date Range"),
                  submitButton("Create Graph")
                ),
                # Show a plot
                mainPanel(
                  plotOutput('makeplot')
              )
)
))

#server.R
#relevant portion only - ggplot

library(shiny)
require(RODBC)
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
library(reshape)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$makeplot <- renderPlot({

p <- ggplot(pdata(), aes(x = Time_Stamp, y = input$yselect)) + geom_point()

print(p)
})
})
```

The data is brought from an online database and is a reactive function. My main issue is that in the user select for the column, it has to be in single quotes, although I would like to transfer it over to the ggplot function without the quotes so it acts as the column name. I've also tried to make a switch statement within the 'y = ' but I get the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your ggplot call, you should have `y = input$selecty`to be consistent with your naming in `ui.R`.

Then, if I understood correctly, you should take a look at the `aes_string` function in `ggplot` because `aes` uses non-standard evaluation which allows you to specify variable names directly and not as characters. Here, `input$yselect` is passed as a character so you need to replace in `server.R` :

```
p <- ggplot(pdata(), aes(x = Time_Stamp, y = input$yselect)) + geom_point()
```

with

```
p <- ggplot(pdata(), aes_string(x = "Time_Stamp", y = input$selecty)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I hastily & incorrectly retyped the selecty while fiddling around with it trying to make it work. And aes_string works, thank you!